# How to check/compare whether four variables are same or different using conditional statement in C# or C++

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, visual-c++, conditional-statements

I have 4 variables having values as a=50;b=100;c=500;d=1000;
If all the values are the same then count =1,else if any two values are same then count = 3,if any three values are same then count = 2.
I can easily find out if all values are the same but in the rest two cases .

Which is the best conditional statement to find the count with minimal code.

The code that i applied:

```
int a=50,b=100,c=500,d=100;
if (a == b && a == c&& a ==d)
            {
                i=1;
            }
            else if (a != b)
            {
                if (a !=c)
                {
                    if (a != d)
                    {
                        i = 4;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm confused to how to search for condition for eg:-a = 50; b= 100;c=100;d=1000;

After i get the distinct value i need to be specific how many values are of similar.How could this be possible ie: if a=50;b=50 c=100;d=1000; so `count` would be 3 but how what about similar values  i.e `int s=2; for 50` ,`s1 =1 for 100` and `s2 =1 for 1000`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the number of distinct values:

```
int i = new [] { a, b, c, d }.Distinct().Count();
```

To get the count of each distinct value:

```
Dictionary<int,int> counts = new [] { a, b, c, d }
    .GroupBy(t=>t)
    .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.Count());
```

This gives you a dictionary that maps each distinct value to the number of times it occurred in the list.

Comment: If there is a need to determine between 3+1 and 2+2 conditions, this won't work. But depends on the OPs needs.

Comment: @Blorgbeard  how could i be specific with similar counts for example .ie: if a=50;b=50 c=100;d=1000; so count would be 3 but how what about similar values i.e int s=2; for 50 ,s1 =1 for 100 and s2 =1 for 1000 –

Comment: Are you asking how to access a Dictionary? `foreach (var k in count) { Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}, Count: {1}", k.Key, k.Value); }`

Comment: @Blorgbeard How should I return the counts from dictionary of each distinct value?? I mean while debugging i can see count[0] has a key and value like {5,2} but how should i get the value .Yes i just want how to access .

Comment: @Blorgbeard :Is the Same code applicable in C++,because when I tried  i get the following error :`error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'`

Comment: No, C++ is a completely different language.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of try i found a code that was indeed working to my need

```
  int a ,b,c,d;  
    List<int> lst = new List<int> { a, b, c, d};
                int res = (from x in lst
                           select x).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: This is just a different version of what Blorgbeard posted.

Comment: @slugster how could i be specific with similar counts  for example  .ie: if a=50;b=50 c=100;d=1000; so count would be 3 but how what about similar values i.e int s=2; for 50 ,s1 =1 for 100 and s2 =1 for 1000